# Type inference when inheriting generic type and constraint

Tags: c#, .net, generics, interface

I am building an interface to allow NHibernate convert from custom types to strings and vise versa.

```
public interface IStringToTypeConverter<T>
{
    T FromString(string value);
    string ToString(T value);
}
```

Where the type `T` could be anything.  For this example I am going to use an enum, I know NHibernate has facilities to convert enums, but this is the simplest example of the problem.

```
public enum TransactionStatus { Failed, Pending, Succeeded }

public class TransactionStatusConverter : IStringToTypeConverter<TransactionStatus>
{
    public TransactionStatus FromString(string value)
    {
        return (TransactionStatus)Enum.Parse(typeof (TransactionStatus), value, true);
    }

    public string ToString(TransactionStatus value)
    {
        return value.ToString();
    }
}
```

So far so good, but the problem arises when I try and specify `TransactionStatusConverter` as a generic type to a class that has a generic type and constraint of `IStringToTypeConverter<T>`.

```
public sealed class CustomStringType<TConverter, TType> : IUserType where TConverter : IStringToTypeConverter<TType>, new()
{
    public object NullSafeGet(IDataReader rs, string[] names, object owner)
    {
        var value = NHibernateUtil.String.NullSafeGet(rs, names[0]) as string;
        var converter = new TConverter();
        return converter.FromString(value);
    }

    public void NullSafeSet(IDbCommand cmd, object value, int index)
    {
        var converter = new TConverter();
        ((IDataParameter)cmd.Parameters[index]).Value
            = converter.ToString((TType)value);
    }
}
```

The usage of this class in NHibernate:

```
Property(x => x.Status, map =>
{
    map.Column("TransactionStatusID");
    map.Type<CustomStringType<TransactionStatusConverter, TransactionStatus>>();
});
```

Where the type constraint of the `Type<>()` function is `IUserType`.

My problem is, I feel that in `map.Type<CustomStringType<TransactionStatusConverter, TransactionStatus>>();` that `TransactionStatus` is redundant as it should be inferred through the type of the converter.

How would I write `CustomStringType` this so my mapping code reads as `map.Type<CustomStringType<TransactionStatusConverter>>();` ?

Comment: I may be wrong, but won't the `new()` constraint on `TConverter : IStringToTypeConverter<TType>, new()` force the `TType` to be a `class` or `struct` (when in your case it's an `enum`)?

Comment: @AndrewCoonce Nope `T : new()` still works with `enum`s, and returns `default(T)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you could omit the type parameter, there would be nothing to prevent you from having a single class that implemented both `IStringToTypeConverter<Foo>` and `IStringToTypeConverter<Bar>`. If that class did both, which type can it safely infer it should be using as the second type parameter for `CustomStringType`? Remember: you can only make logical assumptions that the compiler can make, no cheating and using your domain knowledge to resolve the issue!

On the other hand, if you flip it and provide just the `TransactionStatus` type, secretly hoping that reflection will somehow solve your problems, it might be possible that two different classes both implement `IStringToTypeConverter<TransactionStatus>`. You've still got a problem, you don't know which one is correct for your problem. Again, without domain knowledge, this problem is intractable to the compiler.

Comment: I understand the problem you identified with a class that inherited from `IStringToTypeConverter` twice.  The compiler wouldn't know which one to infer through the type alone.  I'm going to wait for a bit to see if there is an elegant solution to my problem, however.

Comment: I'd love to be wrong, it *feels* like there really should be a good solution... but it also *feels* like a good solution is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

C# does not support partial inference of generic type parameters.

One approach is to use a using alias directive:

```
using CustomStringTypeTransactionStatusConverter = CustomStringType<TransactionStatusConverter, TransactionStatus>;
```

Then you can do like this:

```
map.Type<CustomStringTypeTransactionStatusConverter>();
```

Note that the above approach is better than defining a sublass, because then the base class and the sub class are different types (which is bad if *you consider* them to be semantically the same type and want to use them as such in method parameters etc.):

```
// This is bad because it defines a new type
public class SubClass : CustomStringType<TransactionStatusConverter, TransactionStatus>
{
}
```

---

However, in your specific case you could do some simple refactoring (note that in your code you only use TType to cast an object, and this casting can be done in the TransactionStatusConverter itself)

First introduce an extra interface:

```
public interface IStringToTypeConverter<T> : IStringToTypeConverterUntyped
{
    T FromString(string value);
    string ToString(T value);
}

public interface IStringToTypeConverterUntyped
{
    object FromStringUntyped(string value);
    string ToString(object value);
}
```

Implement the members:

```
public class TransactionStatusConverter : IStringToTypeConverter<TransactionStatus>
{
    public TransactionStatus FromString(string value)
    {
        return (TransactionStatus)Enum.Parse(typeof(TransactionStatus), value, true);
    }

    public object FromStringUntyped(string value)
    {
        return FromString(value);
    }

    public string ToString(TransactionStatus value)
    {
        return value.ToString();
    }

    public string ToString(object value)
    {
        return ToString((TransactionStatus)value);
    }
}
```

And modify CustomStringType:

```
public sealed class CustomStringType<TConverter>
    where TConverter : IStringToTypeConverterUntyped, new()
{
}
```

Now you can use it like this:

```
map.Type<CustomStringType<TransactionStatusConverter>>();
```

Additional note: If you have many converters and don't want to implement IStringToTypeConverterUntyped in each converter (such as in TransactionStatusConverter) then you can let them all inherit from a base class ConverterBase that implements the members declared in IStringToTypeConverterUntyped and also declares abstract members for the members declared in IStringToTypeConverter<**T**>.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I went with something similar to your second example.